# Unity gizmos with custom renderer

Tags: unity, rendering, post-processing

Im working on a small project to learn the basics of post-processing, shaders and other effects in Unity.

My project is in 2D, so I followed [this Brackey's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taMp1g1pBeE) and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiDVoj5VQ4c&). The bloom effect did not work for me with the expiremental 2D renderer, so I used a forward renderer instead.

Problem is, now all of my gizmos (including the camera's gizmos) are gone!

Anyone knows what could be the problem? Do I need to set something in the renderer so it will show?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally turned off the gizmos in the scene / game view? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html

Comment: Whoops you are right! Thanks :)